# How to automatically load the function Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this javascript code

```js
$('select[name="fselect"]').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "add") {
    $('.add').show();
  } else {
    $('.blank').show();
    $('.add').hide();
  }
});

$('select[name="selection"]').on('change', function() {

  if ($(this).val() == "project") {
    $('.project').show();
    $('.gallery').hide();
    $('.event').hide();
    $('.vikinglaw').hide();
    $('.btn-project').show();
  } else if ($(this).val() == "galleries") {
    $('.gallery').show();
    $('.project').hide();
    $('.event').hide();
    $('.vikinglaw').hide();
    $('.btn-gallery').show();
  } else if ($(this).val() == "event") {
    $('.event').show();
    $('.gallery').hide();
    $('.project').hide();
    $('.vikinglaw').hide();
    $('.btn-event').show();
  } else if ($(this).val() == "vikinglaw") {
    $('.vikinglaw').show();
    $('.event').hide();
    $('.gallery').hide();
    $('.project').hide();
    $('.btn-vikinglaw').show();
  } else {
    $('.blank').show();
    $('.project').hide();
    $('.gallery').hide();
    $('.event').hide();
    $('.vikinglaw').hide();
    $('.btn-vikinglaw').hide();
    $('.btn-event').hide();
    $('.btn-gallery').hide();
    $('.btn-project').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <label for="sel1">What action do you want?</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="fselect" name="fselect">
      <option name="nocontent" id="nocontent" value="nocontent">Please select action</option>
      <option name="add" id="add" value="add">ADD</option>
      <option name="edup" id="edup" value="edup">EDIT/UPDATE</option>
      <option name="delete" id="delete" value="delete">DELETE</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="add">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label for="sel1">What page do you want your article to be posted</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="selection" name="selection">
        <option name="nocontent" id="nocontent" value="nocontent">Please select page</option>
        <option name="project" id="project" value="project">Project</option>
        <option name="gallery" id="gallery" value="galleries">Gallery</option>
        <option name="event" id="event" value="event">Event</option>
        <option name="vikinglaw" id="vikinglaw" value="vikinglaw">Viking Law</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do here is that I want to hide first the

```
$('select[name="selection"]').on('change',function(){
```

so that if i click

```
$('select[name="fselect"]').on('change',function(){
if($(this).val() == "add"){
    $('.add').show();
}
```

the `$('select[name="selection"]').on('change',function(){` will show.

Sorry if you don't understand very well english is not my native . I've been doing this for hours but i can't figure out how i can do it. Actually it's already working but i first need to click the `add` button before it works.

Here's an image so that you can fully understand me

[image]

As you can see on the image

On the "What action do you want" on the first load the "What page do you want your article to be posted" must be hide . But the problem is that it's not hiding

Comment: Please make the snippet do what you expect. It is hard to understand what you mean by hide `$('select[name="selection"]').on('change',function(){` - You can assign the handler in the click if you want

Comment: @mplungjan I edited my question . And added some info

Comment: And as a start you can use `switch` instead of `if else if `

Comment: @mplungjan sir i dont quite understand sorry

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML to the snippet I made. We are missing some stuff like btn-...

Comment: If the things you are hiding/showing have a class of "content" you could change most of the script you have to `$('select[name="selection"]').on('change', function() { $(".content").hide(); $("#"+this.value).show(); });`

Comment: You need to ready the DOM so that it understand that it triggers JS functions

Comment: Dat code omg... And ur hiding select options....

Comment: @wintercounter that's what I thought initially but he is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just give initial visibility on page load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add').hide();
});
```

After all, when page finish loading there was no change on select field to trigger the hide for add div.

Comment: Glad you figured out what he meant.

Comment: @mplungjan sorry about that